# Split word by regex

Tags: java, regex, scala, split

I have a line like: `id,name,field,field`.
For example: `"100,artist10XD,0,1"`.

I want to separate them using a regex. The problem is `artistName` can also have a comma (the actual number of commas here is unknown), so I cannot use the `split(",")` function.

The result should be:

```
100
artist10XD
0
1
```

Every line has 4 values.

Please note that I am required to use a regex according to the rules.

Comment: Do you always have 4 values per line? Why can't you use tabs instead of commas to separate the values?

Comment: how many commas can the artistName have?

Comment: If your value has a delimiter in it, you should consider using quotes around that value like so 100,"artis,t10XD",0,1 . When you are seperating that line, treat everything that is in quotes as one single value.

Comment: Try this `^([^,]+),(.*?),([^,]+),([^,]+)$`

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `split(",");`

The result being

```
split[0] == 100, 
split[last -1] == 0, 
split[last] == 1,
```

the rest can be concatenated to be the artistName

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the line by regex, I would try applying regex to the whole line. If you always have 4 values per line and only artist name may contain comma, then your regex may look like this:

```
([^,]+),(.+),([^,]+),([^,]+)
```

You will have 4 groups if the line matches the regex with the artist name in the second group. For example:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(""
    + "100,artist10XD,0,1\n"
    + "100,artist,10,XD,0,1"));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^,]+),(.+),([^,]+),([^,]+)");
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

  if (matcher.matches())
  {
    System.out.println("Artist name: " + matcher.group(2));
  }
}
```

The code above gives the following output:

```
Artist name: artist10XD
Artist name: artist,10,XD
```

Comment: I should read line by line. I should take one line do something then another one.

Comment: That's right, you read line by line and apply the regex to the each line. I updated the answer to include an example.